# How can I combine browser specific CSS together?

Tags: css

While developing my web app, I only tested in chrome. I've finished my responsiveness and wanted to test in other browsers but I saw that Firefox and Edge rendered the height's differently. All of my pages have this white bar along the bottom of the screen and it seems i need to extend the heights by 20px or so.

```
/*FireFox CSS*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @media (min-width: 1366px) {
        #reportPlaceHolder {
            height: 600px;
        }
    }
}

/*Edge CSS*/
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {
    @media (min-width: 1366px) {
        #reportPlaceHolder {
            height: 600px;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have to solve my problem, I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() OR@ supports (-webkit-appearance:none)  { }
```

But i need something like this as the height adjustment seems to be the same on both Firefox and Edge.

This is my current styling for the example element

```
@media (min-width: 1366px) {
    #reportPlaceHolder {
       height: 575px;
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Browsers should not differ on something this basic to begin with. You should perhaps rather try and find the original, underlying cause of the differences you see, than try to find a CSS hack workaround.

Comment: What’s the [mcve] code that *causes* the problem you’re trying to solve? Because solving *that* problem would prevent having to solve *this* problem...

Comment: @04FS I've added an example of how I'm currently styling the element. In Firefox / Edge I've inspected the element, It was targeting the correct media query and height yet it still showed blank area. I there was no zoom on the browser, not sure what else I can look for ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reset? Most resets normalize margins and paddings which differ between elements x-browser.

Solution:
Add a reset to normalize margins and paddings across browsers.

Comment: Hi there, No there are no Reset's in the CSS

Comment: This is the answer. Some browsers add padding and margin to things. Others do not. Since he has no reset this is why some browsers display his height differently. They are adding padding or margin to his elements.